# Singleton and sub classes

Tags: php, pdo, singleton, multiple-instances

I'm working in a project that works with OOP in PHP.

The problem is that when I try to instantiate two subclasses from an abstract class, only the first instance and not both.

DataBase.php:

```
abstract class DataBase {

    private $_connection;

    private static $_singleton = false;

    /**
     * Fetch an instance of the class.
     */
    public final static function connect () {
        if ( self::$_singleton === false ) {
            self::$_singleton = new static();
        }

        return self::$_singleton;
    }
}
```

UserDataBaseManager.php:

```
require_once 'DataBase.php';

class UserDataBase extends DataBase { (...) }
```

ImageDataBaseManager.php:

```
require_once 'DataBase.php';

class UserDataBase extends DataBase { (...) }
```

So, when I'm trying to instantiate ImageDataBase and UserDataBase:

```
$imageDB = ImageDataBaseManager::connect();
$userDB = UserDataBase::connect();
var_dump($userDB);
```

And this prints:

```
object(ImageDataBaseManager)#2 (1) { ["_connection":"DataBase":private]=> object(PDO)#3 (0) { } }
```

So I'm getting only the first class instance, but I want both.

how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initiate a new ImageDataBaseManager it stores the object in $_singleton of the abstract class and next time UserDataBase::connect request a new instance it returns it (static properties does not depends on instances). So it might not be a good idea to subclass a singleton pattern. However to get this working you need to store instance in the subclass not the parent class. Parent class and it's static properties are common to both (in runtime). Refer this code. The subclasses has their own $_singleton to store an instance.

```
abstract class DataBase {

    private $_connection;

    protected static $_singleton = false;

    /**
     * Fetch an instance of the class.
     */
    public final static function connect () {
        if ( static::$_singleton === false ) {
            static::$_singleton = new static();
        }

        return static::$_singleton;
    }
}

class UserDataBase extends DataBase { protected static $_singleton = false; }

class ImageDataBaseManager extends DataBase { protected static $_singleton = false; }

$imageDB = ImageDataBaseManager::connect();
$userDB = UserDataBase::connect();
var_dump($userDB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected static $_singleton = false;

public final static function connect () {
    if ( static::$_singleton === false ) {
        static::$_singleton = new static();
    }
```